# How to replace table name in sql query with regex in Java?

Tags: java, sql, regex

I want to replace table name in a sql query string. I only want to change table name. How can I do that in java with regex?

I do not want to use any dependencies.

For example,

Input:

```
select ... from table1 where/etc ....
```

expected output:

```
select ... from UPDATED_TABLE_NAME where/etc ....
```

Comment: can you give an example of what you are trying to do? are you just trying to replace a table name with another table name in the query?

Comment: i have updated question

Comment: Are there any constraints on how the query will look like? SQL queries can be very complicated, and if there are no additional constraints it will be very hard to write regex which will do only the thing you want it to do... Consider something like ```select foo.x, bar.y, table3.z from (select foo from table1 ) as foo, table2 bar, table3 where foo.z = table3.z and bar.v != "table3"```... How do you know if you shall replace ```"table3"```  or not? how do you know that your replacement will not break short names? How do you even find where the table name is in the query with regex?

Answer (score 1):

If you mutate the query explicitly you open yourself to SQL injection. What you could do is use a PreparedStatement with a **parameterized query** to provide the table name safely.

```java
try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ?")) {
    statement.setString(1, "my_table");

    try (ResultSet results = statement.executeQuery()) {

    }
}
```

If you're insistent on using regex you can just use the query above and replace `?` with the table name. I would not do this in a production environment.

```java
String query = "SELECT * FROM ?";

String queryWithTable = query.replaceAll("?", "my_table");
```

Comment: i dont want to use prepared statement. i just want to update table name

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use a prepared statement? Is it a requirement that you use regex?

Comment: because i do not use any connection

Comment: How are you executing the query without a connection to a database? None the less, updated answer.

Comment: tableName may be equal to the same column name or it may contains the same name. as a result, i want to change the table name using regex